# how to publish app to apple store using windows

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

hi I have been created an app at Xamarin form and I want to publish them to the apps store 
on the google play store that was very easy

the problem of how to publish the app on apple store if I have just windows
I know that I have to use Xcode and just on mac
I think there is some way to do that from windows

Answer (score 0):

Well in fact you could do it without a Mac, installing a Virtual machine as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNprU_bl6e0), after that, you should be able to download the last version of Xcode through the App store within the Virtual machine. Then, within Visual Studio in your Windows, [connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) with your just created Catalina VM.

After that, you colud use [Testflight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bl6LArb-IQU) instead of publishing the app directly on the App store in order to build beta tests.

Regards.